# Como retorno un string en c++

Tags: c++, string

la idea es captar un mensaje y cifrarlo y retornar el string cifrado

tengo el siguiente código

```
string simple_crypt(string _message){
    int j=0;
    int len = alphabet.size();
    int mid = len/2+1;
    string result;

     while (_message[j] != '\0'){
        int n = alphabet.find(_message[j]);
        int aux = (-2)*((n+mid)-len)+n;
        result[j]= alphabet[aux];
        j++;

    }
   return result;
}
```

El problema esta que no retorna el string.

Comment: Quiere usted, por favor, inicializar la variable `result` antes de intentar acceder a un indice que no existe?

Comment: string result(_message.size() + 1, 0)  ya funciona gracias.

Comment: Mentira. Si retorna el `string`. Pero seguramente no contiene lo que esperabas ¿puedes mostrar más código? ¿cómo y dónde se usa la función `simple_crypt`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**El problema esta que no retorna el string.**

Es debido a que no ha sido inicializado y debido a eso la variable nunca ha tenido un tamaño inicial.

Entonces acordando a una de las sobrecargas dadas por el estándar:

```
string();

string (const string& str);

string (const string& str, size_t pos, size_t len = npos);

string (const char* s);

string (const char* s, size_t n);

string (size_t n, char c);


template <class InputIterator>
  string  (InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

Podríamos hacer algo como:

```
std::string simple_crypt(std::string _message)
{
    int j=0;
    int len = alphabet.size();
    int mid = len/2+1;
    std::string result(strlen(_message) + 1, 0); // reservamos memoria para el string y lo llenamos de 0's.

     while (_message[j] != '\0')
     {
        int n = alphabet.find(_message[j]);
        int aux = (-2)*((n+mid)-len)+n;
        result[j]= alphabet[aux];
        j++;

     }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Excelente, gracias por la explicación ya funciona.

Comment: @JorgeLuis si esta respuesta soluciona tu problema márcala como solución. Gracias